# Disappointing inter-thread Queue-based messaging performance (several ms) in python

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, queue

I’m using the python Queue package to send messages between threads.  However, the length of time between when one producing thread sends (queues) a message and another (consumer) thread receives (de-queues) that message seems waaaaay too long.  For example, it takes 2+ ms on average on a Raspberry Pi 3B+, or about 2 ms on a higher-end PC, fwiw (see example code below).  On the Pi, I’m using Debian version: 11 (bullseye), Kernel version: 5.15.  I’ve got the current python3 for that platform, version 3.9.2.  I’ve performed some searches in StackOverflow, but most of the related topics suggest something like using non-thread-safe messaging.

I’m assuming I’m doing something dopey, as 2 ms seems like forever.  I’m attaching my test program below.  Does anyone know how to improve this (especially on the Pi?). Do I have something mis-configured?  I don’t know what I was expecting, but whatever mutex-ing and other overhead is required for the allegedly-thread-safe Queue wouldn’t seem to me to take that long.  I get it that Debian is not an RTOS, but surely this should be faster?

Here's the test code:

```
# This program determines how long it takes for one thread to send a simple object 
# (in this case a numeric value) to another thread using the Queue method.
import time
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import statistics

TIMING_TEST_LENGTH = 20     # Seconds  

Global_Test_Queue = Queue()
# Hold the results of the timing samples
Global_Timing_List = []


def test_producer_thread(out_q):
        
    for i in range(100):
        t = time.perf_counter()

        out_q.put_nowait(t)
        time.sleep(int(TIMING_TEST_LENGTH / 100))  # Chill for a moment before sending another queue object


# Waits on the queue for data (which is simply a tick number) and then records the delay between when the data was sent and
# when that data was received by this function.          
def test_consumer_thread(in_q):
    while True:
        # Get the next input data (this call blocks until data is available)
        ticksWhenSent = in_q.get()
        #-----

        # When did we receive the data?  Right now!
        tickWhenDataReceived = time.perf_counter()
        #print("tickWhenDataReceived=", tickWhenDataReceived)

        # End our thread if things are shutting down
        if ticksWhenSent < 0:
            break

        delayMs = (tickWhenDataReceived - ticksWhenSent) * 1000
        Global_Timing_List.append(delayMs)
        #print("test_consumer thread received data delayed by " + str(round(delayMs, 3)) + " mSecs. Current tick = ", tickWhenDataReceived)



def main():

    try:
        print("Beginning timing test for " + str(TIMING_TEST_LENGTH) + " seconds.")

        consumerThread = Thread(target = test_consumer_thread, args =(Global_Test_Queue, ))
        consumerThread.start()

        producerThread = Thread(target = test_producer_thread, args =(Global_Test_Queue, ))
        producerThread.start()

        time.sleep(TIMING_TEST_LENGTH)  # Let the threads do their thing for a while

        avg = statistics.mean(Global_Timing_List)
        std = statistics.stdev(Global_Timing_List)
        print( "Delay times were (in mSec): " + str(Global_Timing_List))
        print( "Average = " + str(round(avg,3)) + " ms. Standard deviaion = " + str(round(std,3)) + " ms." )

    except KeyboardInterrupt:  

        print ("Received a keyboard interrupt!")
  
    except:  
        print ("Other error or exception occurred!"  )
  
    finally:  
        # Send the shutdown message to the consumer thread.  The producer thread will shut itself down
        Global_Test_Queue.put(-1)

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried killing other processes and bumping the priority of the test program, but to no avail. Can anyone recommend a good profiler package that might help me dig into the source code if there's no answer to this?

(edit) Here's a sample output on the Rpi (Debian-Bullseye):
Beginning timing test for 20 seconds.
Delay times were (in mSec): [2.2789670038037, 1.2069819786120206, 1.3649799802806228, 1.4579780108761042, 1.257980999071151, 1.4789779961574823, 1.199983002152294, 1.329980994341895, 1.2979809835087508, 1.1639830190688372, 1.3999800139572471,
 1.5709770086687058, 1.9739709969144315, 2.065970009425655]
Average = 1.962 ms. Standard deviaion = 0.597 ms.

Comment: On tio.run it takes ~0.03 ms. What OS are you using?

Comment: the above code doesn't show the real issue as it has a sleep, without a sleep it can take up to 10 milliseconds for python to drop the GIL (see `sys.setswitchinterval`) for the OS to start serving the other thread, the problem is likely not dropping the GIL.

Comment: the above code only takes 30-200 microseconds on windows and 10-120 microseconds on linux, which is nearly the correct amount of time required by the OS to make a context switch.

Comment: Even those times seem long.  Last time I measured, it took 4-10 us to make thread running that was waiting on a semaphore, (mostly idle Windows, i7).

Comment: Kelly - I'm on the Pi, I’m using Debian version: 11 (bullseye), Kernel version: 5.15. 

Ahmed - your numbers are more what I expected - thank you, I will look into setswitchinterval().  On what hardware are you running linux?  If it was on a Pi like mine, that might help narrow the problem.   (BTW, I'm new on SO, so not sure how to reply directly to comments).